# Can I block one table from updating?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables in my database one `practitioner` and the second one `practitioner_specialty`, both of them have fields `effective_date` and `expiry_date`. When I use the form to update both if those tables the last `effective_date` and `expiry_date` are being saved to both of the tables instead of two separate ones. 
Is there a way to block one table from updating so I can update only the second one, or maybe is there a way to save it using different id/name so they will be unique ones for `practitioner` and `practitioner_specialty`?

Here are my form and controller used for updating tables.

Controller:

```php
public function updatePractitioner(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $this->validate($request, [
                'effective_date' => 'required',
            ]
        );

        $fields = $request->all();
        $primary_key = $this->PractitionerRepository->getIdName();
        $primary_key_specialty = $this->PractitionerSpecialtyRepository->getIdName();
        $practitioner_specialty_id = PractitionerSpecialty::where('practitioner_id', $id)->value('practitioner_specialty_id');
        $fields[$primary_key] = $id;
        $this->PractitionerRepository->update($fields);
        $fields[$primary_key_specialty] = $practitioner_specialty_id;
        $this->PractitionerSpecialtyRepository->update($fields);
        return back()->with('successUpdate', 'Practitioner has been updated!');
    }
```

update form in blade.php :

```html
<div class="edit-practitioner" style="display: none;">
    <form style="box-shadow: none;" action="/practitioner/update/{{$practitioner->practitioner_id}}" method="post"
          class="j-pro" id="update-practitioner-form">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="j-content">
            <div id="j-row-id" class="j-row">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-5">
                        <div class=" j-unit">
                            <div class="j-divider-text j-gap-top-20 j-gap-bottom-45">
                                <span>Practitioner Information</span>
                            </div>
                            <label class="j-label">{{trans('personalData.effectiveDate')}}</label>
                            <div class="j-input">
                                <input type="date" value="{{$practitioner->effective_date}}"
                                       name="effective_date" id="effective_date">
                            </div>

                            <label class="j-label">{{trans('personalData.expiryDate')}}</label>
                            <div class="j-input">
                                <input type="date" value="{{$practitioner->expiry_date}}"
                                       name="expiry_date" id="expiry_date">
                            </div>

                            <label class="j-label">{{trans('personalData.phoneNumber')}}</label>
                            <div class="j-input">
                                </label>
                                <input type="tel" value="{{$practitioner->phone}}"
                                       name="phone" id="phone">
                            </div>

                            <label class="j-label">{{trans('personalData.mobileNumber')}}</label>
                            <div class="j-input">
                                <input type="tel" value="{{$practitioner->mobile}}"
                                       name="mobile" id="mobile">
                            </div>

                            <label class="j-label">{{trans('personalData.email')}}</label>
                            <div class="j-input">
                                <input type="email" value="{{$practitioner->email}}"
                                       name="email" id="email">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-1 j-unit"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-6">
                        <div class="j-divider-text j-gap-top-20 j-gap-bottom-45">
                            <span>{{trans('settings.specialty')}}</span>
                        </div>
                        <select name="practitioner_specialty_id_update"
                                id="practitioner_specialty_id_update"
                                class="form-control-practitioner required">
                            @foreach($specialties as $specialty)
                                <option
                                    value="{{$specialty->specialty_id}}">{{$specialty->name}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                        <label class="j-label">{{trans('personalData.effectiveDate')}}</label>
                        <div class="j-input">
                            @isset($practitioner_specialty->practitioner_specialty_id)
                                <input type="date" value="{{$practitioner_specialty->effective_date}}"
                                       name="effective_date" id="effective_date">
                            @endisset
                            @empty($practitioner_specialty->practitioner_specialty_id)
                                <input type="date" name="effective_date" id="effective_date">
                            @endempty
                        </div>

                        <label class="j-label">{{trans('personalData.expiryDate')}}</label>

                        <div class="j-input">
                            @isset($practitioner_specialty->practitioner_specialty_id)
                                <input type="date" value="{{$practitioner_specialty->expiry_date}}"
                                       name="expiry_date" id="expiry_date">
                            @endisset
                            @empty($practitioner_specialty->practitioner_specialty_id)
                                    <input type="date" name="expiry_date" id="expiry_date">
                            @endempty
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="j-divider j-gap-bottom-45 j-gap-top-10"></div>
            <button type="submit"
                    class="btn btn-editpanel btn-success btn-round">Save changes
            </button>
            <!-- end /.footer -->
            <button id="update-cancel-button-practitioner" href="javascript:window.location.href=window.location.href" type="button"
                    class="btn btn-editpanel btn-danger btn-round">Cancel
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you use the same array for both of the tables, hence the reason to update all the fields. You can try to exclude the ones for one form and add them to the other, for example:

```
$practictionerFields = $request->except('expiry_date', 'effective_date');
$practictionerFields[$primary_key] = $id;
$this->PractitionerRepository->update($practictionerFields);

// and use the other $fields array for the PractitionerSpecialty model.
```

Comment: But if I exclude 'expiry_date' and 'effective_date' it will exclude all 4 values from the form, isn't it?

Comment: which 4 values? It will exclude just those two items and it will return everything else.

Comment: In the form you can see that I have 'expiry_date' and 'effective_date' for $practitioner and $practitioner_specialty. So 2 for practitioner and 2 for practitioner_specialty. If I exclude 'expiry_date' and 'effective_date' from request it doesnt get any of those values, but I need one set for practitioner and one set for practitioner_specialty.
Requesting last two values for example could solve my problem but I dont think there is a way to do that.

Comment: as I said above you will use your $fields as you already have them for the one and use the other property as I gave it above for the model for which you don't want to update them, instead of using the same array for both models.

Comment: hmm, ok but still if I fill in form all 4 values only practitioner_specialty will update, values for practitioner will al update except  'expiry_date' and 'effective_date'. I want to update them too.

Comment: and you cannot have fields with the same name in one form, the one at the bottom will always override the values on those at the top. You should add different name attributes to differentiate them.

Comment: you asked to block update on fields, but as you comment now you want different field values to be used for both tables. So you need to rephrase your question.. And follow my comment above, you need to either use different forms or different name attributes, otherwise you will override the values every time.

Comment: Ok, maybe I formed my question badly but yeah this is what I mean sorry. Now when the name of the input value is different than in the DB it doesn't save, for exaplme when I rename last two values for a dates to 'expiry_date_specilaty' and 'effective_date_specilaty' it doesnt save to db bc names don;t match. Cna I rename them in the controller after receiving them form the request? @nakov

Comment: Yes you can, use `$practictionerFields['effective_date'] = $request->get('effective_date_specilaty');` as an example, do the same for the other field.

Comment: yeah, thanks a lot did it somewhat similar and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LOCK query here.
lock is a flag associated with a table. MySQL allows a client session to explicitly acquire a table lock for preventing other sessions from accessing the same table during a specific period. A client session can acquire or release table locks only for itself. It cannot acquire or release table locks for other sessions.

You can read more here: http://mysqltutorial.org/mysql-table-locking